# Turning C# methods into C++ methods

Tags: c#, c++, interop, cuda, gpgpu

I'm exploring various options for mapping common C# code constructs to C++ CUDA code for running on a GPU. The structure of the system is as follows (arrows represent method calls):

C# program -> C# GPU lib -> C++ CUDA implementation lib

A method in the GPU library could look something like this:

```
public static void Map<T>(this ICollection<T> c, Func<T,T> f)
{
   //Call 'f' on each element of 'c'
}
```

This is an extension method to ICollection<> types which runs a function on each element. However, what I would like it to do is to call the C++ library and make it run the methods on the GPU. This would require the function to be, somehow, translated into C++ code. Is this possible?

To elaborate, if the user of my library executes a method (in C#) with some arbitrary code in it, I would like to translate this code into the C++ equivelant such that I can run it on CUDA. I have the feeling that there are no easy way to do this but I would like to know if there are any way to do it or to achieve some of the same effect.

One thing I was wondering about is capturing the function to translate in an Expression and use this to map it to a C++ equivelant. Anyone has any experience with this?

Answer (score 7):

There's [CUDA.Net](http://www.gass-ltd.co.il/en/products/cuda.net/) if you want some reference how C# can be run on GPU.

Comment: I think you'll find that you can't run C# on a GPU like you said, but rather that you can lauch CUDA kernels from C#.

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, I'm not sure I fully understand what you are getting at.  However, you may be interested in this project which converts .Net applications / libraries into straight C++ w/o any .Net framework required.  http://www.codeplex.com/crossnet

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the following process to accelerate some of your computation using CUDA from a C# program:

- First, create an ***unmanaged*** C++ library that you P/Invoke for the functions you want to accelerate.  This will restrict you more or less to the data types you can easily work with in CUDA.
- Integrate your unmanaged library with your C# application.  If you're doing things correctly, you should already notice some kind of speed up.  If not, you should probably give up.
- Replace the C++ functions inside your library (without changing its interface) to perform the computations on the GPU with CUDA kernels.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.  I'm not very expert at C#, but I think an ICollection is a container of *objects*.  If each element of c was, say, a pixel, you'd have to do a lot of marshalling to convert that into a buffer of bytes or floats that CUDA could use.  I suspect that would slow everything down enough to negate the advantage of doing anything on the gpu.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do would be to write an own [`IQueryable` LINQ provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546158.aspx), as is done for [LINQ to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx) to translate LINQ queries to SQL.

However, one problem that I see with this approach is the fact that LINQ queries are usually evaluated lazily. In order to benefit from pipelining, this is probably not a viable solution.

It might also be worth investigating how to implement Google’s [MapReduce API](http://labs.google.com/papers/mapreduce.html) for C# and CUDA and then use an approach similar to [PyCuda](http://mathema.tician.de/software/pycuda) to ship the logic to the GPU. In that context, it might also be useful to take a look at the already existing [MapReduce implementation in CUDA](http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_home.html#state=detailsOpen;aid=f6a4e7d4-7f25-41f8-aa92-83305b61867d).

Answer (score 0):

That's a very interesting question and I have no idea how to do this.

However, the [Brahma library](http://brahma.ananthonline.net/) seems to do something very similar. You can define functions using LINQ which are then compiled to GLSL shaders to run efficiently on a GPU. Have a look at their [code](http://sourceforge.net/projects/brahma-fx/) and in particular the [Game of Life](http://brahma-fx.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/brahma-fx/trunk/Source/Samples/OpenGL/GameOfLife/Form1.cs?view=markup) sample.